# How to declare (not define) a spark udf

Tags: scala, apache-spark

How does one **declare** a `udf` - i.e in a `base class` or `trait` that would need to be overridden:

Here is a `similarity udf` declaration:

```
val simUdf: udf( (entityA: Seq[String], entityB: Seq[String]) => Double)
```

But it does not compile:

```
Error:(29, 18) ';' expected but '(' found.
  val simUdf: udf( (entityA: Seq[String], entityB: Seq[String]) => Double)
```

Note that `def` instead of `val` results in the same error

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is just a `UserDefinedFunction`, so you can declare it by:

```
val simUdf: /*org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.*/UserDefinedFunction
```

Comment: I had found this but was too busy to update /answer my own question. So happy awards.

Answer (score 0):

[udf function](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.2/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/functions.scala#L3174) returns [UserDefinedFunction](https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/branch-2.2/sql/core/src/main/scala/org/apache/spark/sql/expressions/UserDefinedFunction.scala) type. You can just pass different implementation to udf function. Here is what I mean:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrame
import org.apache.spark.sql.expressions.UserDefinedFunction
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions._ // for udf and lit

trait Foo {
  def name: String
  def calc(n: Int): Int
}
class Bar extends Foo {
  def name: String = "Bar"
  def calc(n: Int): Int = n + 1
}
class Baz extends Foo{
  def name: String = "Baz"
  def calc(n: Int): Int = n * 2
}

val foo1: Foo = new Bar()
val foo2: Foo = new Baz()

def process(df: DataFrame, foo: Foo): DataFrame = {
  // Pass exact implementation to udf function
  val udf1: UserDefinedFunction = udf(foo.calc _) // _ to make it partially applied
  df.withColumn("calc", udf1(col("n")))
    .withColumn("name", lit(foo.name))
}

val data: Seq[Int] = Seq(1, 2, 3)
val df: DataFrame = data.toDF("n")

val r1 = process(df, foo1)
println("foo1: ")
r1.show()

val r2 = process(df, foo2)
println("foo2: ")
r2.show()
```

Result:

```
foo1: 
+---+----+----+
|  n|calc|name|
+---+----+----+
|  1|   2| Bar|
|  2|   3| Bar|
|  3|   4| Bar|
+---+----+----+

foo2: 
+---+----+----+
|  n|calc|name|
+---+----+----+
|  1|   2| Baz|
|  2|   4| Baz|
|  3|   6| Baz|
+---+----+----+
```